# react axios State won`t set at first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

i`m trying to get some data from an api.

```
class Article extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        Articles: []
    }   
}
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/articles')
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({Articles: res.data})
    })
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
           {console.log(this.state.Articles)}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

My problem is when i try to get some data i get Errors like Undefined...

and thats because first time render runs the value is '[]' and after that the value updated.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the articles array is empty and accordingly render the content :

```
class Article extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        Articles: []
    }   
}
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/api/articles')
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({Articles: res.data})
    })
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
           {this.state.articles.length > 0 && console.log(this.state.articles)}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The above code snippets checks to see if the articles array is of a length greater than 0 and if yes, it executes the statement in conjunction. You can do a lot of things with this property like displaying a loading spinner until your request completes and you can actually render the data.

Answer (score 1):

Set a basic demo value that will be in the array. This will immediately be replaced with the values of the API. You can use something like *please wait, fetching data*. If the user has a stable connection this demo value won't even be seen